# how to show last row of SQL query result in (php) <tfoot> and exclude in <tbody>?

Tags: php

My database colleague built a couple of views and SP's for me so I can focus on html/php.

One is a query that shows a "total" row at the bottom of the table.

I want to:

1. Exclude this last row on my `<tbody>`
2. Show this single row in my `<tfoot>`

Why don't I just show everything in `<tbody>` since the totals row will always show at the bottom anyway? Because I want my `<tfoot>`'s `<td>'s` `colspan` to be different, for presentation purposes.

How can I do this using php alone?

I'm using basic PDO:

```
foreach($table as $row) {
    echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$row['Item'].'</td> 
            <td>'.$row['Amount'].'</td>
          </tr>';
}
```

Comment: You would find the number of rows returned with **num_rows()** call. Track the number of rows you output in <tbody>, and once you're on the last row, output a <tfoot> instead. Be careful about the order of rows returned -- you will need to sort (ORDER BY) or something to ensure that you really get the totals row as the last one.

Answer (score 1):

This should work as long as the last row is not exactly the same as any other row.

```
$last_row = end($table);

echo '<tbody>';
foreach ($table as $row) {
    if ($row === $last_row) continue;
    echo '<tr>
        <td>'.$row['Item'].'</td> 
        <td>'.$row['Amount'].'</td>
    </tr>';
}
echo '</tbody>';

echo '<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td>'.$last_row['Item'].'</td> 
        <td>'.$last_row['Amount'].'</td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>';
```

If it's possible that the last row is not unique you can use the key instead:

```
$last_key = count($table) - 1;

echo '<tbody>';
foreach ($table as $key => $row) {
    if ($key === $last_key) continue;
    echo '<tr>
        <td>'.$row['Item'].'</td> 
        <td>'.$row['Amount'].'</td>
    </tr>';
}
echo '</tbody>';

echo '<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td>'.$table[$last_key]['Item'].'</td> 
        <td>'.$table[$last_key]['Amount'].'</td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>';
```

Comment: FYI, `tfoot` should be printed before `tbody`  "TFOOT must appear before TBODY within a TABLE definition so that user agents can render the foot before receiving all of the (potentially numerous) rows of data." http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3

Answer (score 0):

```
$total = 0;
foreach($table as $row) {
    $total += $row['Amount'];
    echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$row['Item'].'</td> 
            <td>'.$row['Amount'].'</td>
          </tr>';
}
    echo '<tr>
            <td>Total:</td> 
            <td>'.$total.'</td>
          </tr>';
```

You don't need to use thead or tfoot if you do not intend to use them to style your content or in some cases SEO purposes.

Comment: I disagree. `tfoot` is perfect for that. If you do your way, you can't sort your table with JS for example. And it's not because **today** he does not want to style his content that **tomorrow** he wont. I do not -1, but it's a bad advice IMHO.